# Regex to extract time in format HH:MM:SS from string

Tags: regex

I have this string

```
*** Sampled system activity (Sun Oct 31 10:57:41 2021 +0100) (1007.04ms elapsed) ***\n
```

I need to extract `10:57:41`

I try with

```
^([0-1]?\d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?\d))?(?::([0-5]?\d))?$
```

or

```
^(?:(?:([01]?\d|2[0-3]):)?([0-5]?\d):)?([0-5]?\d)$
```

But it doesn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping it simple, I suggest just using:

```regex
\b\d{1,2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\b
```

It is unlikely that anything in your input text *other* than a time component would match this.  Here is a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/IPXBwv/2) showing the pattern working.

Comment: Technically, you don't know that the times before 10:00 are double digits like 09:00, they might be  9:00.  Maybe make the first digit(s) into `\d{1,2}` ?

Comment: @ChrisMaurer I guess it would depend on the format mask used to generate the OP's particular input.  I have edited my question per your suggestion in any case.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern does not match due to the anchors `^` and `$` which assert the start and the end of the string.

If you remove the anchors, you have `([0-1]?\d|2[0-3])(?::([0-5]?\d))?(?::([0-5]?\d))?` which will give [partial matches](https://regex101.com/r/VABYXX/1) as the last 2 groups are optional.

If you remove the `?` from the groups, you are left with superfluous non capture groups, which can be omitted as well. Now you have `([0-1]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]?\d):([0-5]?\d)`

For a match only, you can omit the capture groups, and turn the first capture group in a non capture group. To prevent partial matches, you can add word boundaries `\b`

The simplified pattern:

```
\b(?:[01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xPAzzv/1)